# Trying to run blender on a Lenovo thinkpad x270

Tags: hardware

UPDATE:
Problem SOLVED, I installed a previous version of blender that only requires a two core CPU and now the issues are gone!

Is my computer model too weak for Blender, or is there a fault in my device?

I experience lots of issues when working in Blender with a Lenovo thinkpad x270. It mainly happens when I am working with several objects in a scene, and often gradually builds up during the work session, which makes me think there is something wrong with the memory on my computer, but what do I know, I am not a rocket surgeon. Does anyone have similar experiences?

Specs on the device: integrated Intel HD Graphics 620, 16 gb DDR4, Intel i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz . Here is a video with the glitches:

https://youtu.be/mZWuLEKoJgk

Comment: Interesting! I know that my Blender interface acts really weird if I have bad drivers installed. Consider upgrading your graphics card drivers?

Comment: 1: If you use the Steam version of Blender: Don't. Use the Blender Launcher instead for the convenience.
2: Check for driver/windows updates.
3: Reinstall Blender
4: If it gradually gets worse the more you do, consider reducing the undo steps in the settings. I doubt, that this is an issue with 16 gigs of RAM and such a rather simple scene, so it is a big "maybe", which is why it deserves only spot 4.

Comment: Which previous version of blender did you install? I am having a lot of crashes with my MacBook (2016), which has a 3,1GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5. So reading your update really makes me wonder if I should switch to an older version of blender!

Comment: I installed blender 3.0.1